# How can I remove Tables and replace them with DIVs?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm not using jQuery.
I want to remove all table tags (table,td,tr,etc.) and their respective closing tags, while keeping the content. I can't edit the code that creates this HTML. It generates something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
              <div>
                 <a></a>
              </div>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to remove all the junk so it just ends up like this:

```
<div>
     <a></a>
</div>
```

I've searched for a while and I can't find anything like it.

Comment: Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: I don't even know what a crawler is. I'm trying to parse HTML generated by a webapp so that I can style it and move it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are working on the DOM (client side) and have a reference to the table:

```
// table references the table DOM element
var keep = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    tds = table.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    td, i, l;

// extract the content of each cell
for (i = 0, l = tds.length; i < l; i++) {
    td = tds[i];
    while(td.firstChild) {
         keep.appendChild(td.firstChild);
    }
}

// insert the content before the table (or where ever you want)
table.parentNode.insertBefore(keep, table);
// remove the table
table.parentNode.removeChild(table);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/XbN2m/)

This iterates over all cells and appends each child node to a [`DocumentFragment` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DocumentFragment). By doing this, the child node (the content we want to keep) is removed from the table. Then all of them are inserted before the table and the table is removed.

---

If you have the HTML as string, you can generate the DOM by creating a dummy element:

```
var dummy = document.createElement('div');
dummy.innerHTML = html;

var table = dummy.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
// or table = dummy.children[0];
```

If this is not what you want, you have to provide more information.

Comment: That seems good, but is there a way to do that on multiple tags?

Comment: As in, don't just strip the TD tag, strip tables and tr and so too.

Comment: That's what the code is already doing. It basically *extracts* all the contents of the `td` elements and then removes the whole table. I added some comments.

Comment: What your code seems to do is remove all the tables in an element. I just want to do it universally for the entire document. I'm now using
var keep = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for(var i = 0, l = tds.length; i < l; i++) {
    var children = tds[i].childNodes;
    for(var j = 0, ll = children.length; j < ll; j++) {
        keep.appendChild(children[j]);
    }
}
table.parentNode.insertBefore(keep, table);
table.parentNode.removeChild(table);

but I seem to be doing something wrong.

Comment: I had a (logical) mistake in my code. I corrected it and provided a demo. Please see my update.

Comment: Nice and clean. +1 for the fact alone that you did not recommend jQuery as the first thing.

Answer (score 0):

See this plugin that does exactly what you require

https://github.com/ryandoom/jquery-plugin-table-to-div